# I have written a code in Python where even if i am using a break statement and continue still its going into an infinite loop in Python:

Tags: python, infinite-loop, break, continue

The below code is running however when I am trying to exit out of the code it goes into an infinite loop where even if i type in 1 still it does not break out of the loop. I am a beginner in Python please can anyone help me??

Here is my code,

```
import urllib2
import sys

urlToRead = ('https://www.google.com')

crawledWebLinks = {}

while urlToRead !='':
    try:
        urlToRead = raw_input('Please enter the Next weblink to crawl')
        if urlToRead == '':
            print ('Ok Existing the Loop')
            break
        shortName = raw_input('Please enter a short Name for the Url to Read  ' + urlToRead)
        webfile = urllib2.urlopen(urlToRead).read()
        crawledWebLinks[shortname] = webfile
    except:
        print (sys.exc_info()[0])
        stopOrproceed = raw_input('You want to Stop or Continue, Please type in 1 to stop or anything else to Continue')
        if stopOrproceed == 1:
            print ('Okies we are stopping')
            break
        else:
            print ('lets continue')
            continue


print (crawledWebLinks.keys())
```

Comment: `stopOrproceed` is a string. It will never compare equal to the integer 1. Your if statement should probably be something like `stopOrProceed == "1"` or `int(stopOrProceed) == 1`.

Comment: `raw_input` returns a string. Your input is `"1"`, not `1`.

Answer (score 2):

The following few lines are the ones causing problem,

```
stopOrproceed = raw_input('You want to Stop or Continue, Please type in 1 to stop or anything else to Continue')
if stopOrproceed == 1:
    print ('Okies we are stopping')
    break
```

You see `raw_input` gets input and stores it as a string. So after getting the value from user. your `stopOrproceed` variable would have `"1"`

And when you check for `stopOrproceed==1` --> `"1"==1`. Which is definitely not equal in Python. So **always false is evaluated** And hence the control never goes inside the `if` and thus *you never `break`*.

Try changing that to this,

```
if stopOrproceed == "1":
        print ('Okies we are stopping')
        break
```

Comment: the last suggestion (typecasting) is a bad idea, since it most likely will lead to an unwanted TypeError

Comment: Yes I know maybe I should mention that.. Thanks buddy @Dimgold

Comment: thanks a lot Vishnu....it worked great I used it with int and with string tried both and it worked fine. Thanks a ton. :)

Comment: If it did work. Accept the answer. click the little *tick* below downvote :)